# Перевод SQL запроса в LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

Здраствуйте. Есть такой SQL запрос

```
SELECT e."Id", e."FirstName", e."SecondName", e."Patronymic",
s."DeptName" AS MainSubdivision, 
CASE WHEN s."Id" = ss."Id" THEN NULL ELSE ss."DeptName" END AS SubordinateSubdivision
FROM "Subdivisions" AS s
JOIN "Subdivisions" AS ss
ON s."Id" IN (ss."IdSubordinate", ss."Id")
JOIN "PositionEmployees" AS pe
ON pe."IdSubdivision" = ss."Id"
JOIN "Employee" AS e
ON e."Id" = pe."IdEmployee"
WHERE s."IdSubordinate" IS NULL
```

Я пытаюсь перевести его в LINQ но не совсем понимаю как реализовать вот такую операцию `ON s."Id" IN (ss."IdSubordinate", ss."Id")`
Буду очень признателен за помощь 
вот схема БД и модели из EntityFramework

```
public class Subdivisions
{
    public Subdivisions()
    {
        InverseIdSubordinateNavigation = new HashSet<Subdivisions>();
        PositionEmployees = new HashSet<PositionEmployees>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? IdSubordinate { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }

    public Subdivisions IdSubordinateNavigation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subdivisions> InverseIdSubordinateNavigation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PositionEmployees> PositionEmployees { get; set; }
}

public class PositionEmployees
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long IdEmployee { get; set; }
    public long IdSubdivision { get; set; }

    public Employee IdEmployeeNavigation { get; set; }
    public Position IdPositionNavigation { get; set; }
    public Subdivisions IdSubdivisionNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }

    public PositionEmployees PositionEmployees { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Схема БД]

Comment: Ваши названия свойств вроде `IdEmployee` не соответствуют соглашению EF, они должны называться наоборот же `EmployeeId`. Или вы используете FluentAPI?

Comment: Будет проще, если вы опишите что выбирает вам SQL-запрос словами

Comment: кмк, синтаксис Linq не позволяет перенести "как есть" такую конструкцию :( но в вашем случае это просто проверка на равенство `s.Id` любому из двух `ss.IdSubordinate, ss.Id`, можно просто разделить на 2 отдельных джойна с собственным условием

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = from s in Subdivisionsess
        from ss in Subdivisionsess
        where s.Id == ss.Id || s.Id == ss.IdSubordinate
        join pe in PositionEmployeesess
        on ss.Id equals pe.IdSubdivision
        join e in Employees
        on pe.IdEmployee equals e.Id
        where s.IdSubordinate == null
        select new
        {
            e.Id,
            e.FirstName,
            e.SecondName,
            e.Patronymic,
            MainSubdivision = s.DeptName,
            SubordinateSubdivision = s.Id == ss.Id ? null : ss.DeptName
        };
```

Но на самом деле вы не должны так никогда писать (вся эта куча JOIN), вы должны пользоваться навигационными свойствами.

Если вы опишите словами более подробно что делает ваш запрос, то вам напишут как правильно это сделать с помощью Linq

Comment: Да, ваш запрос сработал спасибо огромное, я чуть позже попытаюсь описать что запрос должен выводить.

Answer (score 0):

навскидку, так:

```
var result = from s in subdivisions
               join ss in subdivisions  on s.Id equals ss.Id
               join sss in subdivisions  on s.Id equals sss.IdSubordinate //! "X equals Y" ни в коем случае не менять местами ХЪ
               join pe in positionEmployees  on ss.Id equals pe.IdSubdivision
               join e in employee  on pe.IdEmployee equals e.Id
             where s.IdSubordinate != null
             select new { e.Id, e.FirstName, e.SecondName, e.Patronymic,
                          MainSubdivision = s.DeptName,
                          SubordinateSubdivision = (s.Id == ss.Id) ? null : ss.DeptName
                        };
```